# Playing a Flash File in Android

Tags: android, flash

Does Android  support flash? If yes then i need an example code to play a flash file. Wonder if we can play a flash file in WebView?

Waiting for reply

Comment: here is the     <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106636/how-to-play-local-swf-files-in-a-webview/6407565#6407565/">link</a>

Answer (score 2):

Until Adobe releases 10.1 for Android, your only chance is if you have a HTC terminal. I wrote about it in [Running Flash apps on Android/HTC Hero](http://blog.zarate.tv/2009/09/13/running-flash-apps-on-androidhtc-hero/).

The thing is that the player that comes with the Hero is a HTC application, not from Adobe. Also it is not part of the standard Android release.

Comment: If flash is not supported in android, wonder how come we have flash games on android: 
http://www.androlib.com/r.aspx?r=flash+game&t=free

Please make things clear here

Answer (score 1):

android version before 2.1 not supported flash,but from 2.1 and later support flash

Answer (score 1):

just open up the brwoser and type in file://sdcard/filename.swf

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is yet possible. I believe the Flash Player 10.1 release is supposed make this possible which is supposed to be released sometime in 2010. I've also heard that FP 10.1 is going to require Android 2.0.

Comment: If flash is not supported in android, wonder how come we have flash games on android: 
http://www.androlib.com/r.aspx?r=flash+game&t=free

Please make things clear here