# Play .swf sound files?

Tags: java, android, flash

my Android application needs to play .swf files, which are sound only.. Is there a plugin or something so I can play them normally? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887758/playing-a-flash-file-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is perfect solution ::**

```
package com.adySol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class adySol extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



     String url ="file:///android_asset/mulberrybush.swf";
    // String url ="http://www.bing.com/";
 WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
 wv.loadUrl(url);

}
}
```

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
>
<WebView android:id="@+id/webView1" android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked, though, when playing a normal .mp3 in the MediaPlayer, the cpu load is ~0%. though, using this to play .swf uses ~6% of the cpu. why is that?  another question: will this also work on phones that are before 2.1 (that are 1.5/1.6)?

Comment: this is work only 2.2 and higher version.

Comment: Is there something to make it work on older devices?

Comment: no . basically there are adobe player must require 2.2 version and old do cant.