# How can i play FLV videos in my android app

Tags: android, flvplayback, flvplayer

i'm developing a news mobile site. I need to be able to play flv videos in my app. How to include a flv player and play flv videos in it. I want to know anyway that i can play flv videos that are in the web.

for example i need to play videos in a format such as in this link

http://www.fortunagate.com/adaderana_apps/video_player.php?video=http://derana.lk/content/video/SriGauthamaSambuddha24-15thJune2014.flv

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing a Flash File in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887758/playing-a-flash-file-in-android)

Comment: http://synesthesia.it/playing-flash-flv-videos-in-android-applications .This tutorial will be of help

Comment: these tutorials are for playing downloaded flv videos right? i want to play flv videos that are in the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android version before 2.1 not supported flash, but from 2.1 and later support flash for more info refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887758/playing-a-flash-file-in-android)